# Cannot connect to Debian Server using openssh

Tags: apache2, debian, openssh

I get the following response after I am authorized:

Running in FIPS 140-2 Mode
Validating FIPS certified DLL...Passed

Connecting to 79.77.3.238:22
   attempting 79.77.3.238:22...     Success!
Username: neilsftp
Password: 
Authentication SUCCESS
Remote Server Disconnected Unexpectedly

Ii have tried Filezilla, DW, Putty. All same.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. does the remote account have a valid shell? As in, shell is listed in /etc/shells, and configured in /etc/passwd?
2. does the remote account have permissions for a shell connection? That's usually a global configuration in sshd_config

Try connecting from a unix-like client with `-vv` on the command line, and post the output.

Comment: Yes and Yes. I have temporarily got in with root fine. I just can't seem to connect using other users' logins.